# Beaultifusoup can't parse all the html

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, html-parsing

I want to write a spider to crawl a html. I use `requests` and `beautifulsoup` ,but I just found out that beautifulsoup can't parse the whole page. Instead, Beautifulsoup just parses half of it.
Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
urls = ['http://www.bishefuwu.com/developer/transmit','http://www.bishefuwu.com/developer/transmit/index/p/2.html']
html = requests.get(urls[0]).content
soup = bs(html,'lxml')
table = soup.find('tbody')
trs = table.find_all('tr')
for tr in trs:
    r = tr.find_all('td')[:3]
    for i in map(lambda x:x.get_text(),r):
        print i
```

and this is [the origin page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpFUf.png), which has row "13107",
but my spider just has half of it, my row stops at "13192".
For testing, I manually save the origin html requested by `requests` and I just found that everything was fine. This error is on Beautifulsoup.
How can I solve it ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, there is nothing wrong with `BeautifulSoup` here. You are parsing a single page under the `http://www.bishefuwu.com/developer/transmit` url - it does not contain the row with number `13107` - it is on the second page.

Iterate over all the urls in the list:

```
with requests.Session() as session:
    for url in urls:
        html = session.get(url).content

        soup = bs(html, 'lxml')

        for tr in soup.select("tbody tr"):
            r = tr.find_all('td')[:3]
            for i in map(lambda x: x.get_text(), r):
                print(i)
```

Note that, you can also think of not hardcoding the list of urls beforehand and handle the pagination in a more dynamic fashion parsing the pagination block on the page and extracting the available page numbers.

Comment: Appreciate a lot !